# Filtering of two paired columns

Tags: r

Consider the following:

```
> df <- data.frame(x = letters[1:15], y = rep(1:3, 5), z = rep(1:5, 3))
> df
   x y z
1  a 1 1
2  b 2 2
3  c 3 3
4  d 1 4
5  e 2 5
6  f 3 1
7  g 1 2
8  h 2 3
9  i 3 4
10 j 1 5
11 k 2 1
12 l 3 2
13 m 1 3
14 n 2 4
15 o 3 5
```

I have another data frame, `df2`, say

```
> df2 <- data.frame(y = c(2, 3), z = c(2, 5))
> df2
  y z
1 2 2
2 3 5
```

I would like to filter **out** the rows of `df` with `y` and `z` values as in `df2`. That is, the output should be something like

```
   x y z
1  a 1 1
3  c 3 3
4  d 1 4
5  e 2 5
6  f 3 1
7  g 1 2
8  h 2 3
9  i 3 4
10 j 1 5
11 k 2 1
12 l 3 2
13 m 1 3
14 n 2 4
```

**The pairing `(y, z)` is important**. I've tried doing something like

`df[!((df$y %in% df2$y) & (df$z %in% df2$z),]`

but here's the problem: if I did this, not only would the pairs `(2, 2)` and `(3, 5)` be filtered, but `(3, 2)` and `(2, 5)` as well, which I do **not** want to happen.

Obviously, I could concatenate the columns and filter based on that, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to deal with this problem.

Comment: I guess you're looking for what's called an "anti join". Here's one way with dplyr: `dplyr::anti_join(df, df2, by = c("y", "z"))`

Comment: @docendo, you can put your comment as a solution

Comment: or `df[!paste(df$y, df$z) %in% paste(df2$y, df2$z),]`

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thank you, I've never heard that term!